# Should I destroy bitmaps and redownload them again everytime the view is binded in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-recyclerview, out-of-memory

I have a `RecyclerView` that has an array of custom objects each containing an empty bitmap and a `String` for the source of the bitmap and a few other attributes. In the `onBindViewHolder` method of my `RecyclerView`, I download the image from the source url and set the bitmap value to the attribute of the corresponding object in the `ArrayList` so next time the view is binded, the image doesn't have to be downloaded again.

What I wanted to know now is if this is considered good practice? since on older devices I realized that after some time I got an `OutOfMemoryException` what is the right way of doing something like this then? Thanks

**EDIT**

I was thinking of trying something like this to keep a limit of loaded bitmaps :

```
int offScreenLimitLeft = position-10;
int offScreenLimitRight = position+10;
if (offScreenLimitLeft>=0){
    itemsArrayList.get(offScreenLimitLeft).myObj.bitmap = null;
}
if (offScreenLimitRight<=itemsArrayList.size()-1){
    itemsArrayList.get(offScreenLimitRight).myObj.bitmap = null;

}
```

Comment: Absolutely not. What you want to do is cache the image locally on the device then re-create them when you need to. There are a bunch of libraries that do this for you like Picasso or Glide. I highly recommend using one of those.

Comment: Downloading is slow, affected by network quality, and uses up data on your customer's data plan.  I agree with @Deev, better to cache the images to local storage if you can.

Comment: @Hod do these type of libraries keep a limit to the cache size ? Or do the have a cache manager of some sort?

Comment: Glide let's you control the cache size.  I'd guess Picasso does too.  Here's an interesting (but somewhat dated) comparison: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Comment: @Hod Nice link there, I started to use picasso but I think I will change to Glide due to the memory performance differences, but there is something botherimg me, for some reason when scrolling the recyclerview after some time and calling a garbage collection the memory doesn't return to its initial value, do I have to manually destroy bitmaps when the imageview is detached from screen or something ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using something like [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html). See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) for examples for downloading and displaying images